# Returning a inherited class as base class type with Web Services

Tags: vb.net, web-services, design-patterns

I suspect I am being very silly here but I have the following setup

```
Class MustInherit myBaseClass
'some stuff

End Class

Class myInheritedClassA 
        inherits myBaseClass

'some more stuff
End Class


Class myInheritedClassB 
        inherits myBaseClass

'some more stuff
End Class
```

I then have a web service that has a method

```
Function getSomeClass(id) as myBaseClass
'a factory here dependent on the id will generate a myInherited Class
return CType(aInstanceOfInheritedClass, mybaseClass)

End function
```

Running this results in the following error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 
   There was an error generating the XML document. ---> 
   System.InvalidOperationException: 
   The type <type> was not expected. 
   Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types 
   that are not known statically."
```

So my question is, is there any way of 'Widening' the inherited class to the base class so this would work?

EDIT: RE: the suggestion regarding XmlInclude(typeof inheritedClass), currently this method could potentially return a number of types of inherited class (i.e myInheritedClassA and myInheritedClassB) is it case of simply having to add each of the inheritedTypes in this tag?

I have amended the example to hopefully make things clearer

Answer (score 3):

You have to use XmlIncludeAttribute to specify the actual types to return.

as per msdn [XmlIncludeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx)

> When applying the XmlIncludeAttribute,
>   specify the Type of the derived class.
>   When the XmlSerializer serializes
>   objects that include both the base and
>   the derived class, it can then
>   recognize both object types.
>
> You can use the XmlIncludeAttribute to
>   include derived classes in service
>   description documents that are written
>   in the Web Services Description
>   Language (WSDL). For example, if a
>   method returns an Object, apply the
>   XmlIncludeAttribute to the method and
>   specify the actual types to return.

below the sample to apply the atttibute to the web method

```
<WebMethod(), XmlInclude(GetType(myInheritedClass))>
Function getSomeClass(id) as myBaseClass
     'a factory here dependent on the id will generate a myInherited Class
      return CType(aInstanceOfInheritedClass, mybaseClass)
End function
```

Comment: @Ramesh The attribute syntax used is that for C# (OP needs VB.NET), but close enough.  Now, good catch, I assumed that the OP was using SOAP encoding, but in case in uses "plain" encoding XmlInclude is the ticket.  I'll fix my response accordingly.

Comment: @mjv you are right!.  C# just came naturally when answering, since its been several years i stopped vb.... will updated that now...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following, i.e. adding the attribute class SoapInclude for whatever different inherited class GetSomeClass() may return ?  (see [this MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.soapincludeattribute.aspx))

**EDIT:** ***SoapInclude*** is if you use SOAP encoding, but do use ***XmlInclude***,  with the same syntax if your web service is not SOAP-per-se  (which it probably is the better for ;-) )

```
<WebMethod(), SoapRpcMethod, SoapInclude(GetType(myInheritedClass)), _
   SoapInclude(GetType(MustInherit))> 

Function getSomeClass(id) as myBaseClass
'a factory here dependent on the id will generate a myInherited Class
return CType(aInstanceOfInheritedClass, mybaseClass)

End function
```